# How to go to a new screen at the end of an animation in SketchFlow

Tags: sketchflow

I have few screens that are wired up using Buttons to navigate to and fro. However, there is one screen that plays an animation when "Loaded" event occurs. I want to go to the "next" screen when the current screen's animation finishes.

Could someone suggest how I can achieve this in Sketchflow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this currently in SketchFlow.

You could fake this by having another screen included into your screen as a component screen, and displaying it at the end of your animation.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think there is a way...

Start out with giving your storyboard a name

```
<Storyboard x:Name="anima"></Storyboard>
```

then go into the ".cs" file

```
//connect it to a listener

Storyboard ST = this.FindName("anima") as Storyboard;
ST.Completed += new EventHandler(AnimaListener);

//the listener
void AnimaListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Services.PlayerContext.Instance.ActiveNavigationViewModel.NavigateToScreen("nameOfTheNewScreen", true); 
}
```

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/e2970c76-6968-40db-a9c2-fca5d56f3f9f

Where i found the navigation code

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30084553/storyboard-completed-event.aspx

Where i found how to link a storyboard to a listener